# MongoDB replica set no primary and nodes unreachable

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I am trying to create a basic replica set in mongoDB with 3 nodes (Primary and 2 secondaries).
It worked for me once but suddenly I see in the rs.status() that the primary node is now secondary and the other 2 are just unreachable. I tried to reconfig, initiate but nothing works. All i accomplished is to remove 2 nodes and stay with 1 primary but whenever I try to add 2 nodes it gives me an error that the node is being reconfigured.

```
rs1:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs1",
        "date" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:11:47.370Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "term" : NumberLong(3),
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
        "votingMembersCount" : 3,
        "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600758614, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:10:14.325Z"),
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600758624, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600758624, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:10:24.326Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:10:24.326Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1600758614, 1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27011",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 3007,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1600758624, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(3)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:10:24Z"),
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 382587,
                        "configTerm" : -1,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27012",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:11:42.692Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit of 500ms",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : -1,
                        "configTerm" : -1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27013",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-09-22T07:11:42.692Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit of 500ms",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : -1,
                        "configTerm" : -1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1600758624, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1600758624, 1)
}
```

Also when I try to create config file with the 3 node memeber and then rs.initiate() i get error messsage "errmsg" : "already initialized".

Comment: Did you start the service? All service are running on your localhost, do you use a dedicated `dbPath` for each instance?

Comment: I run those to start the service : /usr/bin/mongod --config /home/mongodb/data1/db/mongod.cfg --port 27011 &
/usr/bin/mongod --config /home/mongodb/data2/db/mongod.cfg --port 27012 &
/usr/bin/mongod --config /home/mongodb/data3/db/mongod.cfg --port 27013 &

Comment: And how does your `mongod.cfg` files look like?

Comment: ``` echo "replication:
    replSetName: rs1" >> /home/mongodb/data1/db/mongod.cfg
 
echo "replication:
    replSetName: rs1" >> /home/mongodb/data2/db/mongod.cfg

echo "replication:
    replSetName: rs1" >> /home/mongodb/data3/db/mongod.cfg
```

Comment: Please update the question with such details instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *setting up* a replica set, you should initiate it once and then not touch its configuration.

If you are intentionally reconfiguring the RS, then you could change its configuration, but that is not what you are doing in your present scenario.

In a 3 node RS, at least 2 nodes must be up for there to be a primary.

What you should have done when you first encountered the problem was to bring up one of the two down nodes, then the RS should have automatically healed.

You can probably still bring up the down nodes and that might fix everything, assuming you haven't actually changed any settings successfully.